# Error methos 500 Cascading

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Migrate my website to a new server, but I'm having problems filling the combos with CascadingDropDown, I get "Method Error 500", I compared my previous site with the new one, and I see everything the same, my webservice class already has The header [System.Web.script.Services.scriptService ()], in fact in the old server worked fine with the same code and the same web.config, but in the new one, maybe I need to configure or install something.

The operative system is Windows Server 2008R2 and the website is with c# .net framework 4.0

Has anyone managed to solve it?

What I have tried:

- Firewall disabled
- Review permissions in folders
- The webservice answered in url and soapui, but the call inside the cascading control does not resolve it

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution, run this command

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319>aspnet_regiis.exe -i

Note that you will need your command prompt in Administrator mode for it to work.